# Do all NP-hard problems have a reduction from one to another (Either A $\leq_m$ B or B $\leq_m$ A)

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np-hard, np

Given two problems, $A$ and $B$, that are NP-hard. Is either one of the following is true?

1. $A \leq_m$ B
2. $B \leq_m$ A

In other words, is there always a relationship between any two arbitrary NP-hard problems?

Also, I am speaking of polynomial time reductions, but I don't think specifying that will change the answer to this question.

Comment: @PålGD I think the Halting problem is NP-hard, meaning that SAT does reduce to it. But I am asking for any two arbitrary NP-hard problems, not just SAT and the Halting problem. I don't think that SAT reducing to the Halting problem shows that one of the conditions I listed must be true (or if my "conjecture" is false). Forgive me if I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the polytime m-degrees are not linearly ordered even above SAT.

We can get even stronger incomparability: there are sets which aren't even *arbitrary-time Turing-comparable*. This was proved by Kleene and Post (Friedberg and Muchnik proved an elaboration where the sets involved are also required to be c.e.).

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. See you are talking about $NP-hard$ problems. $NP-hard$ problems are not necessarily in $NP$. Thats why they may not be reducible from one another. Cor example $SAT$ is $NP-hard$ as well as $HALT$. $SAT$ can be reduced to $HALT$ but the opposite is not true cause otherwise you will solve the halting problem.

**Edit:** I misunderstood the problem. For any two $NP-hard$ problems $A,B$ itamy not be possible to reduce one to another. For example take $A$ as $NEXP-complete$ problem and $B$ as $coNEXP-complete$ problem. Natural believe is $NEXP\neq coNEXP$. Hence there should not be any reduction from $A$ to $B$ or $B$ to $A$

Comment: Hello. This is not what I am asking. I am asking if there exists a reduction from A to B (SAT to HALT) or B to A (HALT to SAT). For any two problems. Because SAT reduces to HALT, this holds true. I think your question answers if *both* of these conditions are true, not *either*.